# Delete sub-directories based on matching information from column

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, files, directory

I want to keep only those sub-directories that are present in the corresponding directory from CSV file.
The file structure looks something like this:

```
100_folder/
├── folder_11
├── folder_25
├── folder_31
└── folder_41
210_folder/
├── folder_13
├── folder_23
├── folder_31
└── folder_42
```

Information in CSV:

```
Col6,Col26
100,folder_11
100,folder_13
100,folder_41
210,folder_31
210,folder_42
```

Based on the information from the columns, I want to remove the sub-directories that are not present in CSV file.

Here is how I read the file:

```
eCollection=( $(cut -d ',' -f6,26 file.csv ) )
echo "${eCollection[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we can provide solution for you. But where is the fun?

Let me say your requirements look dangerous to me, as every folder not in csv will deleted (imagine typo, wrong file format/line ending or trailing whitespaces)

That said, I will introduce three friends of text file processing in shell (script)

- string manipulation (of variables)
- `grep` text search core-util (file content, read only)
- `find` file search core-util (file name)

Never use code you don't fully understand!

```
#!/bin/sh

csvfile='index.txt'
csvseparator=','

cut -d ',' -f6,26 file.csv > index.txt

for subdir in ./*/*/
  do
    subdir=${subdir%/}
    dir=${subdir%/*}
    parent=${dir%/*}
    subdir=${subdir##*/}
    dir=${dir##*/}
    if grep -Fxq "${dir%_*}$csvseparator$subdir" "$csvfile"
      then
        echo "ok: $parent/$dir/$subdir"
      elif grep -wq "^${dir%_*}" "$csvfile"
        then
          echo "no: $parent/$dir/$subdir"
#          find "$parent/$dir/$subdir" -delete
    fi
done
```

Comment: [Substring Removal](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), [grep](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html), [find](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/moreadv.html)

Comment: just saw your csv file contains more columns than in question, added line `cut -d ',' -f6,26 file.csv > index.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the solution and detailed explanation. It was really helpful. However, I tried uncommenting the #delete line but it's not working. I also printed out till ```dir``` and ```subdir``` by parsing and the directories and sub-directories are printed out correctly. I think there may be some problem in the ```grep``` step. Sorry, I may be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, Indeed it can be dangerous. However, I have just a bunch of symbolic links in them so may be fine. Thanks for sharing the grep tutorials. Very helpful.

Comment: replace *./\*/\*/* with proper path, for example *path/to/parent/\*/\*/* (including trailing slash) where the first star is for dir and second star for subdir. or remove `-F` `-x` flags from grep, not sure why it fails. you can dry run grep in cmd line without `-q` flag. you can add *echo $dir* for debugging purposes or run script via *sh -x script.sh*

Comment: Yes, I had tried replacing the ./ with the proper path earlier. Will try your other recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I tried removing the flags but it seems like it is not changing.

Comment: If I copy data below *"Information in CSV"* in index.txt it works for me. for grep `-x` flag index.txt must not contain gaps or trailing whitespaces because every byte is taken literally. another cause may wrong line ending CRLF instead LF. just start from scratch writing your own script, you will figure it out

Comment: You are totally right. I checked the file and the column contents were read with having quotes inside each item. I removed them by adding  `tr -d \"` to the line `cut -d ',' -f6,26 $AAA_File | tr -d \"  > index.txt` and it worked. Thank you so much! Appreciate it!

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep you can also add quotes in your grep search pattern, although you probably must escape them `\"`